# I can't find DDMS in my android studio

Tags: android

[image]Where do I find DDMS in Android Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should go -

Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor, Here you will find DDMS.[image]

Comment: Please view my edited question. That is the error I'm getting whenever i try to access it

Comment: if you are seeing "Unexpected error while parsing input: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file", then just press "ok"

Comment: Can you see the log file then to find out what was the error message/cause ?

Comment: There is no error in my program! I just cannot access this DDMS. when ever i press ok to that above message it just won't do anythning

Comment: Yes I can see that! It's just a note pad doc with bunch of codes and stuffs. It creates everytime i tried to access to the DDMS

Comment: My best guess it's an bug from Android Studio. Besides you are using "1.0.1" version & the current stable version is "1.1.0". I would suggest you to update your Studio first instead of trying "lots of things". :)

Comment: Oki I'lll try that way! Thanx a lot for your help

Comment: I just reinstalled android studio. But same error same way!

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer! It's just need to download jdk 1.6 or whatever version suits & then install it. Then  copy the javaw.exe from your C:\program files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin folder to the given path on the android eg:C:\Users\ASUS X550L\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64
And then run the javaw.exe as administrator. It's reallt working! :)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using JDK 1.6 anymore. Upgrade to JDK 1.7 u76.